# Organizing Angular code for testing

Tags: angularjs

So I have a decent sized angular application. This being my first Ng project, I wanted to keep it simple and had everything in one file `app.js` when starting out.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory( ... );
app.controller( ... );
...
...
```

As expected, this has now become hard to manage. So I decided to split the functionality within files and combine all of the files using `grunt-concat`. This is how my structure looks -

```
.
├── app.js
├── controllers
│   ├── address.js
│   ├── delivery.js
│   ├── editaddress.js
│   ├── login.js
│   └── newaddress.js
├── filters
│   └── filters.js
└── services
    ├── address_service.js
    ├── cartservice.js
    ├── constants.js
    ├── services.js
    └── transformrequest.js
```

This has worked out quite well and its easy to manage. However, I'm quite at a loss on how to organize for testing.

For example, filters were earlier defined as

```
angular.module("app.services", [])
.factory('CartService', function() {
})
.factory(...)
```

This allowed me to write karma tests properly. Now that filters are across files, and adding
`angular.module("app.services", [])` in each gives an error - I am not sure how to organize my code across files and make it testable.

I looked at [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index.html#L34-L40), but even they have only one file for controllers, services etc.

So my question - how can I organize my code across multiple files and still make it testable in Karma.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am separating my files very similar directory structure like yours.

I am define my app in app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then in the other files you don't have to use the "app" instance. You can reference it this way:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory( ... );
angular.module('myApp').controller( ... );
```

If you use this method, you don't have to concatenate files, you can include them one by one in your html or in karma tests.

I use my camra.conf.js like this:

`...
          files: [
            'lib/angular/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'src/app.js',
            'src/**/*.js',
            'tests/**/*.js'
        ],
...`

Comment: Can you show me how your karma test code looks? Without creating modules for services etc, how are you running unit tests on them? Thanks!

Comment: I do create modules. In app.js I define the module called "myApp". `angular.module('myApp', []);` Then I define a service on myApp with  `angular.module('myApp').factory( ... );`

Comment: You can see an example how to unit test an angular js controller with karma and jasmine: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/